# How to remove /current link in capistrano

Tags: .htaccess, capistrano

I was using Capistrano to deploy my source code to beta and live server.

when I deploy it to the beta server the URL looks like `deploy.abc.com/project_name/current`

I just want to know the way to remove /current from the URL so it will look like `deploy.abc.com/project_name`. I know this should be done using .htaccess and mod-rewrite. But I have no Idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `VirtualHost` (maybe in etc/httpd/vhosts/*.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/deploy.abc.com/www/current #this line change the url

        #some code

</VirtualHost>
```

or the .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #some code

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ current/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this didn't work. anyway thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Do you have restarted apache? You try the first or the second method?